# WCF Transaction Time out

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, transactions, timeout, workflow

I have a WCF service consumed by a Windows Workflow via a transaction. I have a method that calls a stored procedure using EF.

The stored procedure takes a long time to return a result, I get the following exception:

> The transaction under which this method call was executing was asynchronously aborted.

When I set the `TransactionTimeout` via `ServiceBehaviour` attribute, everything works fine:

```
[ServiceBehavior(TransactionTimeOut="00:02:00")]
```

But when the `TransactionTimeOut` was set via `app.config`, it's not working and I get the above exception.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:02:00"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have also tried `<System.transaction>` but I'm still getting the error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the transaction taking longer than 2 minutes?

Comment: No, it takes about 1 minute and 30 seconds

Comment: From what I see on here: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/servicemodel-transaction-configuration), it looks as if you should have the transactionTimeout as part of your behavior node, as it's attribute.

Comment: I don't want hard code the value via the attribute, I just want use the app.config

Answer (score 0):

To increase timeouts use following mark-up:

```
<system.serviceMdel>
    <bindings>
        <httpBinding>
            <binding ... receiveTimeout="..." sendTimeout="...">
            </binding>
        </httpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceMdel>
```

Refer to this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding).

Comment: I’ve already this mark-up, I get a transactionTimeout not a sendTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/servicemodel-transaction-configuration) :
If this attribute is set within a service configuration section, you should apply at least one method of the corresponding service with `OperationBehaviorAttribute`, in which the `TransactionScopeRequired` property is set to `true`.

I have just added `[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]` to the service method, then I consulmed it inside a `TransactionScope` and everything is working fine.